# @ConditionalOnProperty not working when building jar locally although it is working fine when getting included from remote repo

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

To be more specific in the below code if I am providing only the property of MongoDB(spring.data.mongodb) in application.yml  it is throwing RunTime exception stating that

> **PostgresDBPurgeController**  bean can not be created missing spring.datasource
>    but as per @ConditionalOnProperty if the property is not there Bean creation would not happen.

In detail,I have the below code in a common jar and I have 2 different app(1 use postgres as db ,another mongo as db ) which use this same jar and both the apps are working fine when I am including the jar from remote repo.
But when I build the common jar locally and and run the app (which use mongo as db ) locally it is throwing above error.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.data.mongodb", name = "host")

@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.datasource", name = "driver-class-name", havingValue = "org.postgresql.Driver")
public class PostgresDBPurgeController {
```

Comment: its unclear of what you are trying to ask

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan Edited.Thanks